# How to create a component like Bootstrap accordion?

Tags: reactjs

I want a component to behave exactly like Accordion.
I have managed to do that.
But I am facing one issue.

If one question is open and a user tries to open the other question,it closes the first question.
I do not want that.

I want both of them to remain open and it should be closed if a user clicks on the question again.

Here is the code -->

```
class Accordion extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      answer: false,
      selectedQue: null,
    };
  }
 toggleAnswer = (index) => {
    const { answer } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      selectedQue: index,
      answer: !answer,
    });
  };
  render() {
    const { answer, selectedQue } = this.state;
  return (
               <Row className="m-t-10">
                    <Col md={12} sm={12} xs={12}>
                      {map(
                        questionAnswer,
                        (item, index) =>
                          item && (
                            <div key={index} onClick={() => this.toggleAnswer(index)}>
                              <div className="d-flex justify-content-between">
                                <Label
                                  header={item.key}
                                  color={index === selectedQue && answer ? '#406AE8' : '#415070'}
                                />
                                <span className="float-right">
                                  <Icons
                                    className={cx(
                                      'vertical-align-middle',
                                      index === selectedQue && answer
                                        ? 'ac-icon-arrow-up-xs'
                                        : 'ac-icon-arrow-down-xs',
                                    )}
                                  />
                                </span>
                              </div>
                              {index === selectedQue && answer && (
                                <div>
                                 <span
                                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                                      __html: item.value,
                                    }}
                                  />
                                </div>
                              )}
                              <hr />
                            </div>
                          ),
                      )}
                    </Col>
                  </Row>
)
}
}
```